# MySQL Trigger IF statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

Ok, I'm working on this for class and I do not know why I'm getting an error.  I'm pretty new to writing advanced sql scripts so that's probably the issue here but I am trying.  The error I'm getting is:
unexpected '(' expecting ':'
My code... the error comes in on the raise_application_error line.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS DoubleRoomPriceTrigger $$

CREATE TRIGGER DoubleRoomPriceTrigger
    BEFORE UPDATE ON Room
    FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN
        IF Room.RoomType = 'Double' AND Room.price < 100 THEN
            raise_application_error(22, 'Price must be greater than 100 for a double room');
        END IF;
    END

$$
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Tommy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `CALL` before raise_application_error (I assume you have the raise_application_error procedure defined).

```
CALL raise_application_error(22, 'Price must be greater than 100 for a double room');
```

Comment: Oh my god, I thought I had added that earlier and it didn't work.  It works now though and you're awesome.  Thanks!